# Using PHPQuery to select a URL with a query string

Tags: php, phpquery

I want to selecting an XML node based on whether it has a child with a URL attribute set to a certain value.

I think this code shows phpQuery doesn't parse URL correctly... but I may have missed something regarding escaping the =...

Any ideas?

```
<?php
include '../libs/phpQuery.php';
phpQuery::newDocumentXML('
   <doc><item>item 1<link url="http://example.com" /></item>
        <item>item 2<link url="http://example.com?abc" /></item>
        <item>item 3<link url="http://example.com?abc=" /></item>
        <item>item 4<link url="http://example.com?abc=21" /></item>
   </doc>');

echo "<pre>
".
pq("link[url='http://example.com']:first")->parents('item')->xml()
."
".
pq("link[url='http://example.com?abc']:first")->parents('item')->xml()
."
".
pq("link[url='http://example.com?abc=']:first")->parents('item')->xml()
."
".
pq("link[url='http://example.com?abc=21']:first")->parents('item')->xml()
."
</pre>";
?>
```

This is returning

```
<pre>
item 1<link url="http://example.com"/>
item 2<link url="http://example.com?abc"/>
item 2<link url="http://example.com?abc"/>
item 2<link url="http://example.com?abc"/>
</pre>
```

Comment: I agree that it shows that phpQuery isn't working properly but you also might be confused about what `:first` is supposed to do

Comment: The intention of 'first' was to get the first link tha matche (in case there are duplicates). I had changed the order of the links to see if phpQuery was getting the original parsing wrong (and all links were the same internally) or failing in the later search (it seems to be the search that fails). Is this not what first will achieve?

Comment: It's actually not too clear in the css spec but I believe that :first should match the first li, whether it matches or not. So if the first li doesn't match it  should probably return nothing. There's better ways to get the first match.

Comment: Hi - I did more testing - with with duplicate URLs,  :first and :last works as I expected (just let to right). Its not clear which branch of phpquery is current - so think I'll have to debug it myself...

Comment: I just tested it myself, my phpQuery doesn't match these selectors properly. In your example all four `link`'s are `:first` and `:last` as well as `:only-child`, do you see why?

Comment: I found :first and :last worked as expected *excepting* the original problem (ignoring everything from the 2nd '=' in the selector). I tracked that down (answer added) - and is now doing what I need (for now!). Regards!

Comment: Well they don't work as they're supposed to, but if they work as you expect, I guess that's often good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

In phpQuery/phpQueryObject.html around line 749

The attribute and its required value are parsed using

```
                    $value = null;
                    list($attr, $value) = explode('=', $attr);
                    $value = trim($value, "'\"");
```

So the second '=' and everything after are lost (exploded into a third value that isn't captured). I changed this to

```
                // attr with specifed value
                if (mb_strpos($s, '=')) {
                    $value = null;
                    $raw = $attr;
                    parse_str($raw,$ary);
                    $attr = current(array_keys($ary));
                    $value = substr($raw,strlen($attr)+1);
                    $value = trim($value, "'\"");
```

Its a bit (very) naff, but it works for my app!

Note the key is extracted from the 'parse' value, then the value is the remainder of the string.